# is it possible to detect if an xml node is present using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

i have a xml file and i want to know if it is possible to see if the `<VertrekVertragingTekst>` is present in the xml file.

this is the xml node:

```
<VertrekkendeTrein>
<RitNummer>4722</RitNummer>
<VertrekTijd>2014-06-03T09:45:00+0200</VertrekTijd>
<VertrekVertraging>PT2M</VertrekVertraging>
<VertrekVertragingTekst>+2 min</VertrekVertragingTekst>
<EindBestemming>Uitgeest</EindBestemming>
<TreinSoort>Sprinter</TreinSoort>
<Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
<VertrekSpoor wijziging="false">2</VertrekSpoor>
</VertrekkendeTrein>
```

(these nodes are in dutch so dont pay attention to what they say, that is not important)

this is the c# code that i have so far:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ActueleVertrekTijden/VertrekkendeTrein/*");
foreach (XmlNode nodelist2 in nodeList)
{                    
    if (i < 1) //1
        switch (nodelist2.Name)
        {
            case "VertrekTijd": string kuttijd1 = (nodelist2.InnerText);
                var res1 = Regex.Match(kuttijd1, @"\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}").Value;
                lblv1.Text = Convert.ToString(res1); break;
            case "VertrekVertragingTekst": ververt1.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); ververt1.Visible = true; vertpic1.Visible = true; logo1.Top -= 9; lblts1.Top -= 9; break;
            case "EindBestemming": string vertrek1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); if (vertrek1 == "Uitgeest") { lblvia1.Text = "Krommenie-Ass"; } lblbs1.Text = vertrek1; break;
            case "TreinSoort": lblts1.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
            case "RouteTekst": lblvia1.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
            case "VertrekSpoor": lbls1.Text = (nodelist2.InnerText); i++; break;
        }
}
```

i can read out of this file and everything works but i want to know how i can detect the presence of this node?

Comment: lolled @ Kuttijd (Belg)

Comment: @Schuere na een tijdje is je inspiratie weg om variabelen te bedenken

Comment: dat klopt, maar mijn code reviewer houdt daar geen rekening mee :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SelectSingleNode Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var result = node.SelectSingleNode("nodeTocheck");
if(result!=null)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with Linq To Xml based on the following code snippet.

```
XDocument XmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(Doc);
var Query = XmlDoc.Root.DescendantNodes()
                       .OfType<XElement>()
                       .Where(iEl =>iEl.Name.LocalName.Equals("NodeName"));
```

The sequence would contain all nodes of name `NodeName`.

Answer (score 0):

I use **XmlReader** class to read XML files, you can also give it a try
namespace **System.Xml.XmlReader**

**Example:**

```
String xmlString =
            @"<bookstore>
                <book genre='autobiography' publicationdate='1981-03-22' ISBN='1-861003-11-0'>
                    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
                    <author>
                        <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
                        <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
                    </author>
                    <price>8.99</price>
                </book>
            </bookstore>";

        // Create an XmlReader
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            if(reader.ReadToFollowing("book"))
            {
                reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
                string genre = reader.Value;
                Console.WriteLine("The genre value: " + genre);
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something else
            }
        }
```

**Output**

The genre value: autobiography